# How can I successfully connect to an Apache IoTDB cluster version using code commands?

Tags: cluster-computing, cicd, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After I installed the cluster version (1C1D) of Apache IoTDB, I can't connect through coding in the server. I have checked the port and the parameter settings and they all seem to be normal. However, when I use start-cli.sh in the sbin folder on IoTDB environment to log in, I can successfully log in.

Is there anything else I need to configure before I can connect to IoTDB by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `dn_rpc_address` parameter in Apache IoTDB to your actual ip number, and set it to be fixed, since the `-h` parameter of Cli tool in IoTDB needs to be set to real ip.
Also, if you are using Version 1.0, you need to delete the data directory and restart the system. If you are using Version 1.1, this bug is fixed and you do not need to restart.